# VSCode Error: Could not fetch remote environment. Failed to connect to the remote extension host server (Error: WebSocket close with status code 1006)

Tags: visual-studio-code, websocket, vscode-remote-ssh

I have a VScode application and when i try to use the SSH Remote function to connect to external VMs, it comes up with this error:
[Websocket Error in VScode (Windows 11)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5G1E.png)

Now, this just happened all of a sudden. I have always been able to use VSCode to SSH into my VMs but cant anymore. This is happening with my VSCode on WIndows 11. On my Mac, the VS code just works right.

The only thing that I think i have done different was have VS 2022 open at the same time. But this shouldnt cause a Websocket error.
Can anyone help?

UPDATE: I have reinstalled vscode (several times), I have also deleted "/Roaming/Code" and ".vscode" folders. But still same issue. And yes, I have restarted my PC severally too.

Comment: I too observer similar issue while doing double-SSH