Is there a way for me to rectify the error in Visual Studio Code please
Please how would I rectify this error that I am getting in Visual Studio Code which says:

Failed to connect to the remote extension host server (Error: Websocket close with status code 1006)

I have uninstalled and re-installed my Visual Studio Code, including files related to it, but I'm still not able to rectify the error.

seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/71771654/11107541

Try deleting

'/home//.vscode-server/data' or
'/home//.vscode-server' or
'/.vscode-server'

See if it works. This must help you. Or disable all the installed extensions and restart VS code and check if the error persists.
